# Google Sheets: Moving daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly averages

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, moving-average

I have a spreadsheet where I'm collecting data, and entering a date the data is collected. I would like to get the moving averages of collected data in my spreadsheet on a daily, weekly, monthly, and yearly for charts.

The two columns that I'm working off of are "Date" in column A (when the data was collected) and "Data" in column C (the actual collected data). The date is always increasing and is "mm/dd/yyyy" format. The data in column C are integers, and an almost-always increasing running total, except in four places where manual corrections had to be made.

The collected data is not entered every day, and as such, there are gaps between dates in the "Date" column. Sometimes 2 or 3 days go by without collected data, sometimes more. The largest gap is 98 days without collected data.

E.G.:

```
    + ---------- + - + ----- +
    |     A      | B |   C   |
+ - + ---------- + - + ----- +
| 1 |    Date    |   | Data  |
| 2 |  6/15/2016 |   | 1263  |
| 3 |  6/30/2016 |   | 1371  |
| 4 |   7/1/2016 |   | 1382  |
| 5 |   7/7/2016 |   | 1429  |
| 6 | 10/13/2016 |   | 2588  |
```

I have collected almost 3 years of data across 217 rows.

Getting a moving daily average seems as simple as `=(C3-C2)/DATEDIF(A2, A3, "D"))`. Getting the moving weekly, monthly, and yearly averages are stumping me.

How can I get moving weekly, monthly, and yearly averages for data that isn't entered every day in Google Sheets?

Comment: Here is a CSV of the sheet: https://paste.debian.net/1071037/

Comment: well, can you atleast provide an example how your desired output should look like?

Comment: Essentially, I want to know what the sliding window data differences are across each day, every 7 days, every 30 days, and every 365 days. For example, the date difference between A2 and A3 in my post is 15 days. The data difference is 108 units. That's about 7.2 data units per day, or about 50.2 data units per week. I would expect the weekly differences chart to be less spiky than the daily, and the monthly less spiky than the weekly, and the yearly less spiky than the monthly.

Comment: You need to interpolate between points. Before you try to make a quick formula that gives the result, make sure you understand what the actual values would be if you did have data logged daily: make an expanded table with data for each and every day in the period, and come up with the formulas & results for your averages from that dataset. Share your resulting formulas and what you think the next step is after that.

Comment: Note that averages are not differences, too.

Comment: **question is how you imagine 7 days... 7 days between given dates or 7 days regardless of every day or 7 days between measurements**

Comment: I could fill in the missing days, figure out the daily average between data entry points, and use that to fill in a calculated running total. But then the spreadsheet grows from 217 rows to over 1000, and starts becoming unwieldy.

Comment: This seems like something `QUERY()` could handle, but I'm not sure how to approach it.

Comment: @aaron I'm suggesting you do it for just a subset of data (minimum created table size is 366 rows so you have 2 different yearly values) in order to validate whatever formula you come up with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: 0]

**G2:**

```
=IFERROR(MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $C2)/7, )
```

**H2:**

```
=IFERROR(MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $C2)/30, )
```

**I2:**

```
=IFERROR(MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,     "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+365, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,     "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+365, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $C2)/365, )
```

Comment: The weekly, monthly, and yearly numbers aren't what I would expect though. The data is a running total, like, how many total jumping jacks you've done since some starting date. You started averaging 25 jumping jacks per day, which is about 175 per week, or 750 per month. But as you got in better shape, your daily average improves to say 30 per day. That would be close to 210 per week or 900 per month. Does that make sense? The weekly numbers should be about 7x the daily, the monthly numbers about 4x the weekly, and the yearly about 12x the monthly.

Comment: it does not. what weekly formula does is to extract the weekly range from A:C table and then take last value from C column extraction and subtract it from the first value of  extracted C column and then it divides it by 7

Comment: Ah, Indeed. If I remove the `/7`, `/30`, and `/365` from the calculation, the totals appear to be what I'm looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image: 0]

**E2:** `=(C3-C2)/DATEDIF(A2, A3, "D")`

**F2:**

```
=MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")-1)), $C2)/
 MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY(A2:C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A3,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'")-1)), $A2)
```

**G2:**

```
=IFERROR(MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $C2)/
 MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,   "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+7, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $A2), )
```

**H2:**

```
=IFERROR(MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $C2)/
 MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,    "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+30, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $A2), )
```

**I2:**

```
=IFERROR(MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,     "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+365, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select C 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,     "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+365, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $C2)/
 MINUS(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,     "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+365, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
  limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(QUERY($A2:$C, 
 "select A 
  where A >= date'"&TEXT($A2,     "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and A <= date'"&TEXT($A2+365, "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"))-1), $A2), )
```

Comment: Hmm. Let's say the daily average is 25 units per day for a few months. Then the ballpark should be around 25*7=175 units per week, and 25*30=750 units per month. So for the month of May, I would be interested in the difference between May 1 - May 7 for a week difference. Then sliding that window forward one day, I would want May 2 - May 8 for another week difference. Then May 3 - May 9 for a 3rd week difference, etc. The weekly averages are a sliding 7-day window, the monthly a sliding 30-day window, and the yearly a sliding 365 day window. The problem is, I don't have data for every day.

Comment: I've added answer for fixed sliding window